# How does Apache (or Nginx) send the request data to PHP?

Tags: php, apache, nginx

It's a simple question, but I couldn't find an answer yet, so I figured I ask here. How exactly does Apache (or any other web server) pass the request data to the PHP interpreter?

As far as I'm aware, after finding the correct `index.php`, Apache sends the file to the PHP interpreter to execute it. But how does it pass the request data, that the PHP interpreter (I assume?) uses to populate the superglobals like `$_GET`, `$_POST`, etc?

Comment: I don't know the internals of it specifically, but I suspect each webserver does it slightly differently, even though the end goal is broadly the same. Not sure you can get a single answer for them all. Some, like Apache, even have multiple options for integration.

Comment: $_GET is populated through environment variables and $_POST through stdin